# Need a driving circumstance to drive mc into new world

Tags: creative-writing, plot, ideas

I’m struggling to find a driving circumstance for my character to want to enter train and get better in my fictional world.  I have tried letting the  antagonist try to kill him to drive him there but I’m not sure I want to reveal him as the chosen one from the beginning also I don’t want members of the civilization knowing he’s the chosen one.  I’m trying to find some political or  societal reason to drive the plot at first any ideas or what you’ve seen done well.

Comment: Hi Sean! Questions about what to write - that is, asking us to write your story rather than asking for help with specific, answerable problems - are considered off-topic in Writing SE, since they would require too much information about your story and would be too specific to you. I am voting to close the question for that reason.

Comment: I was asking to see if anyone had seen anything like this done before well not asking for someone to write my story

Answer (score 1):

Setting protagonist on the path to adventure is a very, very common theme in fiction. Unless the protagonist is already in a middle of an adventure, some force must send them there.

1. Disaster. Some kind of tragedy strikes hero's home and there is no choice but leaving it (ex. "Star Wars" ("A New Hope"))
2. Impending disaster. There is no disaster yet, but the hero must travel to prevent one (ex. "The Lord of the Rings")
3. Adventurism. The hero might simply be in a mood for an adventure (ex. "The Hobbit")
4. Natural flow of events. There may be some innocuously looking reasons to leave home. Little did they know what was ahead... (ex. "A Game of Thrones")
5. A chance that shouldn't be missed. The protagonist is given a chance to have their live changed for the better (ex. "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer Stone").